# Elasticsearch NEST MultiGet across multiple indexes

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

I want to run a MultiGet (`mget`) search query on several IDs across two indexes. This is because I have two indexes, but I don't know which index contains my ID. This is the query:

```
GET _mget 
{
    "docs" : [
        {
            "_id": "id1",
            "_index": "index1"
        },
        {
            "_id": "id1",
            "_index": "index2"
        }
        /* ....  */
    ]
}
```

The query works great manually - I get the results and I just ignore the result that returns `found: false`.

`Nest` does not support this functionality, only on one index. So I tried to use the low-level client to achieve this, like so:

```
var data = PostData.Serializable(new
            {
                docs = new[]
                {
                    new {
                        _id = "1",
                        _index = "index1"
                    },
                    new
                    {
                        _id = "1",
                        _index = "index2"
                    }
                }
            });

var response = await lowLevelClient.MultiGetAsync<MultiGetResponse>(data);
```

However, I'm getting the following exception: `Elasticsearch.Net.UnexpectedElasticsearchClientException: 'Constructor on type 'Nest.MultiGetResponseFormatter' not found.'`.

Is this the right way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following will help you achieve what you are looking for with NEST

```
var request = new MultiGetRequest();
request.Documents = new IMultiGetOperation[]
{
    new MultiGetOperation<object>("id1") { Index = "index1" },
    new MultiGetOperation<object>("id1") { Index = "index2" },
};
var multiGetResponse = await client.MultiGetAsync(request);
```

Comment: Hi Rob. Thank you, I actually got to the same answer by myself before I saw yours. I do have an issue now where if I search for documents where ONE of the indexes do not exist - I want to ignore the missing index (`ignore_unavailable` flag basically does that). However, I'm not sure how to use the `ignore_unavailable` flag in `mget` requests. Now if one index is missing, `IResponse.IsValid` is `false`.

Comment: So after a lot of trial an error, it seems that the best way to achieve this is to check the 
 `MultiGetResponse.Hits` property, to check each hit for errors of type `index_not_found_exception`. If the total number of problematic hits match the number of hits, then we can assume that *all* indexes do not exist, and that's an issue.

Comment: @gUnleash maybe instead of `mget` use `_msearch` which supports `ignore_unavailable`? [Docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html)